# Azure kusto unable to create chart

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

The error I got is
"The Line can't be created as you are missing a column of one of the following types: int, long, decimal, or real"

[image] this is my query"   I am looking the chart will display "number of unique resource IDs over time, with an aggregation timespan of 5m"

```
syslog_CL
 | where data_s contains "Reject" 
 | where hostname_s contains "Network1"
 | where TimeGenerated > ago(1hr)
```

is there any suggestion I can add to the query to get the time chart?

Comment: please try to clarify how your schema looks like (e.g. by appending `| getschema` to your query and pasting that in your question), as well as what do you want to plot in a timechart. in your original question, neither of thes are clear

Comment: thanks, I have added the schema on question

Comment: however, you still didn't clarify what kind of timechart you wish to plot (for example: "number of unique resource IDs over time, with an aggregation timespan of 5m")

Comment: sorry, absolutely I am looking as you said "number of unique resource IDs over time, with an aggregation timespan of 5m"  I will add on the question too. thanks much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
syslog_CL
| where data_s contains "Reject" 
| where hostname_s contains "Network1"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1hr)
| summarize dcount(_ResourceId) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
| render timechart
```